# Ignore document folders in URL path of sphinx project

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm constructing a Sphinx documentation and would like to place my `.rst` files in an organized folder structure. However, for my actual URL path I would like to *not* have these sub folders be included in the URL - rather, I would like to have a simple URL path as below:

`[domain-url.com]/[file-name]`

Is this possible to configure?

Comment: So you want a hierarchy of folders for the RST files but a flat structure for the corresponding HTML files?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I like to have my rst files organized locally - but I wish to avoid this resulting in very lengthy URL paths. Rather, I'd like each HTML page to have a simple URL with just the root domain followed by the file name

Comment: Sphinx has no built-in configuration for this. Perhaps the web server can be configured somehow. I don't think it can be easily accomplished.

Comment: Ok thanks mzjn, appreciate the input